# Inline variable substitution to end at a certain character

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I am working in ArcGIS ModelBuilder.

For one of my models I would like to use an iterator (Iterate Feature Classes) but am having difficulties with the Wildcard.

Here is an example of some of the data files:

```
LC_1990_final,
LC_1990_final_NoWater,
LC_2000_final,
LC_2000_final_NoWater,
**Other additional years with the same naming convention
```

I have a series of models that incorporate this naming convention so I would rater not change all my models.

I am looking to only iterate over the LC_1990_final and LC_200_final and not the LC_1990_final_NoWater and LC_2000_NoWater.

I know I could do *_NoWater if I was looking to further process the NoWater files. However, I am looking to process just the other set of files.

Is there another symbol similar to * that would do a hard stop and allow the iterator only to select LC_1990_final and LC_2000_final?

Comment: Are you using the ModelBuilder from ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  It may or may not make a difference to this particular question.

Comment: I take it you mean https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00400000000r000000 you could try iterate values https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Iterate_Multivalue/00400000000w000000/ - for example ['1990','2000'] and use the identifier LC_%Value%_final and LC_%Value%_final_NoWater just make sure to use %Value% in your output name or you will just overwrite previous iterations (been there, done that).

Comment: If you want to start with the file names then perhaps Calculate Value https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004000000004000000 is a good choice, using a python evaluator "%FeatureClass%".split('_')[1] to get the 2nd token in the file name split by underscores.